# How were the Orishas born?

Tags: africa, yoruba

Orishas are the deities that form the Yoruban pantheon. Their ruler is Olorun. However, while I was reading up on them, I was unable to find out about how the Orishas were created. How were these gods born?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it depends. I listed a few examples below.

At least a number of them are primordial deities. Orunmila, for example, was present at the beginning of creation.

The primordial Orishas "emanated directly from God without any human aid," according to Britannica.

Wikipedia says that Obatala was "brought to life by the smooth breath of Olodumare". Orunto is also a son of Olodumare.

Ogun is also primordial.

Erinle was a great hunter who became an orisha.